# Tampermonkey get downloaded resource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, tampermonkey

So, this web page at load will download a JSON file. I want to look at the content of that JSON, is that possible?

I tried to alter the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open to catch the thing, but it seems that my script run after it was downloaded, so nothing.

By download, I mean on the Network tab of Developer tools, there's a row saying something like "abc.json?blablah".

Note: The file is downloaded by creating a SCRIPT element and attach to BODY, then destroy it afterward (or something, because I can't find it after that).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Download subtitle from wistia
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        console.log("generic request: " + url);
        if (url.indexOf(".json") > -1) {
            console.log("json request");
            this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    // parse content
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log("huh is coming");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }, false);
        }

        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Use `// @run-at document-start`

Comment: @wOxxOm not sure if the run-at not working, or something, but I still couldn't get the JSON

Comment: Debug the code using `debugger` statement or `console.log('something')`. Anyway, without seeing the code, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @wOxxOm I included the code, could you take a look?

Comment: Looks okay and actually works on a couple of sites I've tried. Try looking at that elusive script element in Devtools (F12 key) -> Sources -> right pane -> Event listener breakpoints -> Script -> Script first statement. Or use `Any XHR` in XHR breakpoints above. Reload the page while devtools is opened and it should catch the culprit.